# Where would I put the file search contains certain words

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this and I ran the debug and it did not give me any errors. Where can I put the search function for files with certain words? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This was one I was trying to use

```
 var filesIterator = folder.searchFiles('title contains "Untitled"');


function MoveFiles() {
  var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
  var SourceFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').getFiles();
  var DestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1hbuV93CsdOeHkZWLES8BhXYMrayoKTBr');
  while (SourceFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = SourceFiles.next();
    DestFolder.addFile(file);
    SourceFolder.removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you move any move any files?

Comment: Nope, I figured if the debug did not give any errors it would work. When I ran the script it didn't move the files

Comment: So now you need debug it.  Run it again and view executions or stackdriver error logging or take a look at the execution transcript.

Comment: I looked in executions or stackdriver error logging or execution transcript and they are not showing any errors, but still nothing is moved. I am very new to scripting and I usually copy others and make it fit to my own needs, but have been unsuccessful in getting the script right. I need something to search a folder with certain words in the file name and move it to another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Find and Move Files

This function will show a prompt where you can enter the string to complete the query 'title contains "the string"'.  You also have to provide the **id** of the folder to search for and the **id** of the destination folder.

```
function findAndMoveFiles() {
  var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Id');
  var DestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Id');
  var result = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter the string to complete the search query');
  var qry = Utilities.formatString('title contains "%s"', result.getResponseText());//you just need to enter the string that gets put into %s
  var SourceFiles = SourceFolder.searchFiles(qry);
  while (SourceFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = SourceFiles.next();
    DestFolder.addFile(file);
    SourceFolder.removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

Enter the script into a gs file in the script editor.  You can run the script from the script editor once it start a dialog prompt will appear on the spreadsheet so make sure to switch back to the spreadsheet at that point.

You can also run it from a menu by entering in the following code:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Search Menu')
  .addItem('Find and Move Files', 'findAndMoveFiles')
  .addToUi()
}
```

You will need to save it to the Script Editor and select it and run it one time to get the menu into the spreadsheet.  Also it will display in the spreadsheet upon opening the spreadsheet next time.

- [DriveApp Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles(String))
- [UI Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)

Also checkout all of the features in the help menu of the Script Editor.

[image]

Comment: Got it working with the Spreadsheet...Took a little while to figure out how to get it to work. One other question, Is there a way I can do the search for the file name that begins with certain words instead of the word in the middle of the file name? I tried using a * but it gave me a Invalid Argument.

Comment: I have not really used the search parameters very much but here's the [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-parameters) in the documentation.

Comment: That should help out. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I suppose you could use the "contains" in the search params but when get into the iterator where `var file=SourceFiles.next();` you could use file.getName and then do a regular expression match using start of line ^ character.  I bet if you show your example code and ask that question again you'll find someone who knows regular expressions a lot better than me.